# How to configure BlueMix to push data from Device A to Device B?

Tags: android, push-notification, push, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to make an application that sends its state to a Bluemix server. The server makes a push to another device to update the desired state. Until now, I managed to send information to Bluemix using IOT. From this moment, I do not know more what to do. I need to set up something so that when the information reaches the server is already transferred to another device.
Also, I already set up a key in the GCM and already configured in the service of Push Notifications for Blue Mix. Would anyone be able to tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend utilizing the Push Notifications REST API to achieve your goal here. By making calls to the REST endpoints implemented by the Push Notifications service you will be able to dynamically create and send push notifications to devices that need updating all from your sever.

We have documentation related to using the Push REST API at https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/t_restapi.html and you can try the calls out for yourself with our Swagger Docs here https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/

Comment: Thanks, for using the Cloudant I also need use REST API?